# How to retrive the value in Wso2esb using Xpath

Tags: xpath, wso2, xpath-2.0, wso2-esb

I am using wso2esb4.7.0 i have written jms proxy so i wish send my data to endpoint but i am unable process this 
my proxy is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="MediaMoveQueue"
       transports="jms"
       startOnLoad="true"
       trace="disable">
   <description/>
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property name="readingspayload" expression="$body"/>
         <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
               <p:hello xmlns:p="http://jaxws.youtility.in/">
                   <arg0 xmlns="">$1</arg0>
               </p:hello>
            </format>
            <args>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('readingspayload')"/>
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <!--header name="Action" value="hello"/-->
         <log level="full"/>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="http://192.168.1.2:8282/services/media_move_service_i_f"
                        format="soap11"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
</proxy>
```

in this proxy i am getting the data like this if i log this esb
my log is look like this

> {"timestamp":1383715637698,"tmpfilename":"313d79a7-c29b-4e1a-9609-818610a6a66b.pdf","objecttype":"Punch","filename":"enterprisedb_order.pdf","totalfilesize":994086,"uuid":"313d79a7-c29b-4e1a-9609-818610a6a66b","objectid":"313d79a7-c29b-4e1a-9609-818610a6a66b","fullpath":"/tmp/tmpmedia//313d79a7-c29b-4e1a-9609-818610a6a66b.pdf","deviceId":"911202500210109","filemimetype":"PNG"}

but i need to just send that json format of data to my endpoint for that i have tried this xpath but its showing errors of name space how would i get this

```
$axis2ns58:text
```

but its throwing errors i wish to send that data to my endpoint
i have tried this but i need above format of data only

```
//soapenv:Body
```

its giving like this result

```
   <soapenv:Body xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> 
      <axis2ns58:text xmlns:axis2ns58="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">{"timestamp":1383715637698,"tmpfilename":"313d79a7-c29b-4e1a-9609-818610a6a66b.pdf","objecttype":"Punch","filename":"enterprisedb_order.pdf","totalfilesize":994086,"uuid":"313d79a7-c29b-4e1a-9609-818610a6a66b","objectid":"313d79a7-c29b-4e1a-9609-818610a6a66b","fullpath":"/tmp/tmpmedia//313d79a7-c29b-4e1a-9609-818610a6a66b.pdf","deviceId":"911202500210109","filemimetype":"PNG"}</axis2ns58:text> 
</soapenv:Body>
```

but i wish to send below data to my endpoint even payload also not supporting for this

```
{"timestamp":1383715637698,"tmpfilename":"313d79a7-c29b-4e1a-9609-818610a6a66b.pdf","objecttype":"Punch","filename":"enterprisedb_order.pdf","totalfilesize":994086,"uuid":"313d79a7-c29b-4e1a-9609-818610a6a66b","objectid":"313d79a7-c29b-4e1a-9609-818610a6a66b","fullpath":"/tmp/tmpmedia//313d79a7-c29b-4e1a-9609-818610a6a66b.pdf","deviceId":"911202500210109","filemimetype":"PNG"}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try doing

```
//soapenv:Body/ns:text
```

and set the namespace

```
ns="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload"
```

Comment: BUt its defining some other way for every request <axis2ns58:text xmlns:axis2ns58="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload"> is changing its adding the <axis2ns58:text number is increasing with every request

Comment: The name of the namespace (e.g. axis2ns58) is irrelevant.  Think of it as a variable that maps to the namespace URL.  You can call it whatever you want, you don't need to use axis2nsxx (and I would suggest you don't).  The number is increasing but the namespace URL is remaining the same.  You could use //soapenv:Body/abcdef:text, and if abcdef was equal to the same namespace URL they'd be equal.

Comment: thanx a ton for clear explanation..i will get back to you soon

Answer (score 0):

Try this: 
Modify your Proxy service as below :

Instead of `<property name="readingspayload" expression="$body"/> , modify it to below,
      <property xmlns:ns="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload"  name="readingspayload" expression="$body/ns:text/text()"/>`

```
 ****
```

Hope this should work!!!